# How do I reposition a moving animation during a gameplay?

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

I am using the Android Studio IDE, with the libGDX framework to develop a game. It is a clone of the Pac-Man game with a similar gameplay to flappy bird.  The concept is that the pac man moves through the planks while avoiding the ghosts coming from the right direction, that are moving off straight into the left direction (not chasing the position of the player). I am not sure how I create a 'for loop' for the ghost animations, I want the ghosts to consistently reposition and re-appear from the right side after a few seconds, with the exception that they completely gone off the screen initially.

The class for one of the Ghosts.

```
public class Blinky {

private Vector3 position; //x y and z axis
private Rectangle bounds;
private Texture texture1;
private Animation blinkyAnimLeft;

public Blinky(int x, int y) {

    position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    Texture texture1 = new Texture("blinkyLeft.png");
    blinkyAnimLeft = new Animation(new TextureRegion(texture1), 2, 0.5f);
    //bounds = new Rectangle(x,y,texture1.getWidth() / 2, texture1.getHeight());
}

public void update(float dt) {

    blinkyAnimLeft.update(dt);
   //bounds.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
}

public Vector3 getPosition() {
   return position;
}

public TextureRegion getTexture() {
    return blinkyAnimLeft.getFrame();
}

//public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return bounds;
}

  public void dispose() {
    texture1.dispose();
  }
}
```

Ghosts and Player initialised in the GamePlayState Class

```
public class GamePlayState extends State  {
//Variables
private float timePassed = 0;
private Texture background;
public static final int WALK = 1;
public static final double GHOST_WALK = 0.5;
private static final int PLANKS_SPACING = 125;   //gap betwen the planks
private static final int PLANK_COUNT = 4;
private Array<Obstacle> planks;
private Player player;
private Blinky blinky;
private Inky   inky;
private Texture missile;

public GamePlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    player = new Player(50, 100);
    blinky = new Blinky(400, 220);
    inky = new Inky(400, 240);
    //   missile = new Texture("missile.png");

    background = new Texture("black.jpg");
    cam.setToOrtho(false, PacMan.WIDTH/2, PacMan.HEIGHT/2);

    planks = new Array<Obstacle>();

    for (int i = 1; i<= PLANK_COUNT; i++) {
        planks.add(new Obstacle(i * (PLANKS_SPACING + Obstacle.PLANK_WIDTH)));
    }
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {

}

@Override
public void update(float dt) {
    handleInput();
    player.update(dt);
    blinky.update(dt);
    inky.update(dt);
    cam.position.x = player.getPosition().x + 80;    //update the position of the camera with the bird

    //update when pacman cam viewport has passed plank
    //make cam follow the player
    for (Obstacle plank: planks) {

        if (cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/1) > plank.getPosTopPlank().x + plank.getTopPlank().getWidth()) {

            plank.respositionPlanks(plank.getPosTopPlank().x + ((Obstacle.PLANK_WIDTH + PLANKS_SPACING * PLANK_COUNT )));
        }
        if (plank.collision (player.getBounds()))
        gsm.set(new GamePlayState(gsm));
    }
    cam.update();
    }

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {

    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    sb.draw(background, cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth/2), 0);
    timePassed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    //Moving Inky
    sb.draw(inky.getTexture(), inky.getPosition().x, inky.getPosition().y);
    inky.getPosition().x -= GHOST_WALK;

    //Moving Blinky
    sb.draw(blinky.getTexture(), blinky.getPosition().x, blinky.getPosition().y);
    blinky.getPosition().x -= GHOST_WALK;
```

Comment: please post code snippet instead of images ?

Comment: I've just added the code. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should get x, y( and z) position from Vector3.
Then check for borders

```
if (inky.getPosition().x < 0){
    Thread.sleep(/*a few sdeconds*/2000);/*Android studio would ask you about wrapping it with try - catch*/
    inky.setPostion( x + /*screen x size*/,
        inky.getPosition().y,inky.getPosition().z)/*add setter in ghost class*/
}
```

In fact, this is not the best way to do it, but the simplest one

Comment: Thanks for the response I tried what you suggested but it did not work. Setter method in Ghost class
    `public void setPosition(float x, float y) {

        x = position.x;
        y = position.y;


      }` GamePlayState code `if (inky.getPosition().x < 0) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            inky.setPosition(inky.getPosition().x + 
           PacMan.WIDTH,inky.getPosition().y);

           }`